# Storing v-for lists in a variable

Tags: vuex, vuejs3, v-for

I am rendering a list using v-for, and the loop contains another v-for loop that iterates and lists images.
I can store the contents of the first loop in variables and access them later on, however, I can't figure out a way to access the second loop with images and cannot store it into a variable.

Is there anyway I can do it?

**My main loop with the nested loop:**

```
<div class="asset-card" v-for="asset in assets" :key="asset">
      <div class="asset-details">
        <h3 class="bold">{{ asset.name }}</h3>
        <h4 class="semibold">{{ asset.project }}</h4>
        <h5>{{ asset.client }}</h5>
        <h5>Aroflo {{ asset.aroflo }}</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="img-container">
        <img :src="asset.mainImg" alt="asset image" />
      </div>
      <div class="thumbnail-container">
        <div class="thumbnail">
          <img
            v-for="thumb in asset.thumbs"
            :src="thumb.thumbnail"
            alt=""
            :key="thumb"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="button-container bold">
        <button @click="moreDetails(asset)">Project Details</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**The modal I am sending the data to:**

```
<div class="details-container">
            <div class="asset-details">
              <div>
                <h3>{{ assetDetail }}</h3>
                <h4>{{ projectDetail }}</h4>
                <h5>{{ arofloDetail }}</h5>
              </div>
              <div>
                <span @click="closeDetails"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="image-container">
              <img :src="mainImage" id="mainImage" />
            </div>
            <div class="thumbnail-container">
              <div class="section">
                <!-- modal thumbnails -->
                <img :src="thumbImg" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**My method to assign loop value to variables** :

```
methods: {
   moreDetails: function (asset) {
     this.assetDetail = asset.name;
     this.projectDetail = asset.project;
     this.arofloDetail = asset.aroflo;
     this.mainImage = asset.mainImg;
     this.assetDetails = !this.assetDetails;
   }
```

Comment: Show your code attempts

Comment: So you mean to say that `asset.thumbs` is not working in `moreDetails(asset)` ? Or maybe you want to know how to pass data from one component to another in vue?